# Why Does the <P> tag creates a black background here? and how do I get rid from the border?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, colorbox

I'm trying to create some colorbox element,
and I can't figure out why does the

tag creates a black background here? and how do I get rid out of the external black border? (tried to modify the CSS with no success)

[This is the Fiddle with all relevant code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/N4xZb/)

Comment: I see neither a black background, nor a border.

Comment: Did you click the link "Inline HTML"...?

Comment: Apologies. I shall look at it again.

Comment: in your code open `<p>` tag is missing .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black border come from this css:

```css
#cboxContent{margin-top:32px; overflow:visible; background:#000;}
.cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
#cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#cboxLoadedContent{background:#000; padding:1px;}
#cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#000;}
```

Try this instead;

```css
#cboxContent{margin-top:32px; overflow:visible; }
.cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
#cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#cboxLoadedContent{ padding:1px;}
#cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
```

Fiddle: [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/N4xZb/4/)

Comment: Just checked and this is indeed the cause. The black 'border' was just the black background of the box giving it the illusion that there was actually a border.

Comment: @display_name Thanks! there's still some transparent gap above the text line, how can this be eliminated?

Comment: @rockyraw Take a look at this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/N4xZb/5/); I have added a `padding-top:1px;` to the div containing the `<p>`tag. This is a little dirty, but seems to work.

Comment: @display_name i'm afraid it's a bit too dirty :) what if for example I want to have a full size image as the background of the div, in the exact same dimensions? the padding would be noticeable in that instance :)

Comment: found it. You need to add `display: inline-block` instead of padding. That will solve it :) @rockyraw

Comment: @display_name `#cboxLoadedContent{ display: inline-block;}`? it doesn't seem to change anything, unless I misunderstood you

Comment: @display_name, looks like adding `style="margin-top:0px;"` to the P tag is solving this. I wonder though if your suggestion can be applied as well somehow, just for general knowledge :)

Comment: no, add it to this one `<div style="height:400px;width:600px;background-color:#FF9; display:inline-block;" align="center"><p>h</p></div></div>`. That should do the trick. Avoid the `margin-top` fix :) @rockyraw

Comment: but then I would have the same gap between the letter "h" and the top border of the frame